# AngularJS - replace function on displayed data

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I'm showing a table of data with "ng-repeat", like so:

```
<table ng-init="mydata=..." ...>
<tr ng-repeat="item in mydata">
<td>{{item['name']}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to replace something in the content of "item['name']" for display.

I try it like so:

```
<td>{{item['name'].replace(/aaa/gi,'bbb')}}</td>
```

This way the display in the TD is empty!

When I do a simple replace, it works fine, for example:

```
<td>{{item['name'].replace('aaa', 'bbb')}}</td>
```

Is there a problem with the replace function on AngularJS data when using Regex or am I doing something wrong??

I also need this replace for special characters, like apostrophe (" ' ") and quotes ( " )...

I should mention that in this case, I cannot perform the replace anywhere else AND cannot bring the initial data set other than "ng-init" on the table element.

Comment: You need to create a filter. An example can be seen [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046928/how-to-use-regex-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs

Comment: As I remember you can't use regex into `{{...}}`. For beter maintenance, I would use filter as @RArun says or single method: `{{replaceMe(item['name'])}}`