# Filtering AngularJS By First Letter Using <select></select> html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to filter a ng-repeat function (I am not understand what that is mentioned, forgive me). Currently I want to make a filter but the filter function is based on the first letter of the option for example, in a set of array/string, I would like to filter that the first letter is "A" or "B" something like that.

Here is the code for the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <title>Belajar Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('tesapp', []);
      app.controller('tesCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.DapatkanItem = function(){
          $http.get('json/item.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.item = data;
          });
        };

        $scope.DapatkanItem();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="tesapp" ng-controller="tesCtrl">
    <h1>Mencoba Filtering</h1>
    <div class="col col-4">
      <label class="select">
        <select name="gender" ng-model="alfabet">
          <option value="0" selected disabled>Alphabet</option>
          <option value="1">A</option>
          <option value="2">B</option>
          <option value="3">C</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch="alfabet">
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | orderBy: 'preparation' | orderBy: 'name'">
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == ''">{{tes.name}} kosong</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '1'">{{tes.name}} satu</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '2'">{{tes.name}} dua</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '3'">{{tes.name}} tiga</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | orderBy: 'preparation'">
          <li>{{tes.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

What do you think? For example I want to filter by the first letter of the array is "A", then I will pick the A in `<select>` tag and done, but in this case the problem is I don't know what function that I have to use to filter by the first letter.

Comment: Your question is not clear; and this is what I uderstood from your question *You need to apply filter on drop-down which is controlled by a value which was taken out from another drop-down (in your case, this drop-down contains values "A", "B" and "C")?* Is my understanding correct??

Comment: yeah that's what I mean, I also get confused about how to deliver the good question since I am not experience in this thing and still learning. So the technical way is this, when the dropdown value is: A, then the list are filtered with every value with FIRST LETTER of A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can see this thread: [how-to-use-regex-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046928/how-to-use-regex-with-ng-repeat-in-angularjs)
I would change your select to

```
<select name="gender" ng-model="alfabet">
  <option value="^">Alphabet</option>
  <option value="^(A|a)">A</option>
  <option value="^(B|b)">B</option>
  <option value="^(C|c)">C</option>
</select>
```

And then use a filter like the following

```
ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | regex:'name':alfabet | orderBy: 'preparation' | orderBy: 'name'"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I still have problems with this code, I don't know either regex can help what I want... I have tried it earlier but the result is still lack (even I also copied the angularJS code that I get from your link and I edit it of course according to my own app) but still didn't work, do you have another idea in mind? Thank you so much

Comment: Include your angular code in your question up top plz

Comment: My goodness, the code is working... wow, thank you so much :)